# Android keypad Enter key event not working

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, text-editor

Hi I am working with Text Editor in my android app. I want the cursor to move to next line in edittext when i touch enter key in android-softkeyboard and have  to execute a method,so i used setOnKeyListener() because when i pressed the key it goes to this method and execute myMethod().
 My main problem is when ever i used this (edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);) line of code it is entering into the setOnKeyListener() method and executes  myMethod well but the cursor position is still in same line,if i removed that line the cursor position is updating (goto next line) but setOnKeyListener() is not executing.
Please suggest me how to work on it ,My code is

```
  edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    myMethod();

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try return "false":

```
if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, edittext.getText(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      myMethod();

      return false; // here
 }
```

Comment: Instead of `setOnKeyListener`, try to implement `setOnEditorActionListener`. And remove this line `edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);` 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Still not working if i removed that line of code it cannot go to the setOnEditorActionListner but the cursor is updating. Here is the code                                     edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
               if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                  MyMethod();
                   return false;
               }

Comment: You can also try `addTextChangedListener` and `TextWatcher`.  
`editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == '\n') {
                 myMethod();
            }
        }
    });`

Comment: i have to execute some functionality when enteer key pressed from keypad i think it is not possible  by using addTextListner and TextWatcher.I think you did't read my question

Comment: I understand your question and I tried two of the proposed options and me both options work, you can check for yourself [link](https://github.com/sergeyostrovskyy/test.git)

Comment: Thank you  Sergey  O i tried your code and I got cursor updation but it is not going to onKey() override method so I am unable execute myMethod.